# How can i write the code of Pascal's triangle?

Tags: code, source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pascal's triangle in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/pascals-triangle-in-tikz)

How can i write the code of Pascal's triangle? Pleae help me.Thank you.

Comment: Use the `fp` package. It has code to calculate and typeset a Pascal triangle.

Comment: The question has been closed; but if you feel that the duplicate question we pointed at doesn't work for you, please edit your question telling what's needed to spot the problem.