# How can I draw a different version of Pascal's triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pascal’s triangle in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/pascals-triangle-in-tikz)

I know that, at [Pascal's triangle in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/pascals-triangle-in-tikz), we have discussed about the code of the pascal's triangle. Please, help me to get the following way of visualizing the Pascal triangle.

[image]

Comment: If you change the line to `\node at (\k,-\n) {$\binomialCoefficient{\n}{\k}$};` Caramdir's answer, you are done. So if you don't mind I'll vote for a duplicate.

Comment: No, I don't mind.

Comment: My pleasure. :)