# Factorial program in Latex without using any package

Tags: programming, loops

I've heard that Latex is a Turing complete language. So I went on to write a Fibonacci program in Latex and I succeeded (without using packages). Now I want to write a factorial program in latex (without using packages). I wrote the following code:- (includes debug texts)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\typein[\n]{Enter the value of n :-}

\newcommand{\scaleup}[2]{
     \newcount\ofac
     \ofac #1\relax
     \newcount\ntemp
    \ntemp \the#2\relax
    {
        \loop
            \ifnum \ntemp>1
                \advance#1 \the\ofac\relax
                \advance\ntemp -1\relax
                nfac(m) = \the#1
                \nfac \the#1\relax


        \repeat
    }
}

\newcommand{\factorial}[1]{
    \newcount\num
    \newcount\nfac
    \newcommand{\nfacinloop}{1}
    \num #1\relax
    \nfac 1\relax
    \loop
        \ifnum \num>0
            % \huge{\the\num}
            % \scaleup{\nfac}{\num}
             \newcount\ofac
             \ofac \nfac\relax
             \newcount\ntemp
            \ntemp \the\num\relax
            {
                \loop
                    \ifnum \ntemp>1
                        \advance\nfac \the\ofac\relax
                        \advance\ntemp -1\relax
                        nfac(m) = \the\nfac
                        \nfac \the\nfac\relax
                        \renewcommand{\nfacinloop}{\the\nfac}
                        nfacinloop = \nfacinloop

                \repeat
            }           
            nfac = \the\nfac
            nfacinloop = \nfacinloop
            % \huge{\the\num}
            \advance\num -1\relax


            % \huge{\the\num}
    \repeat
}

\factorial{\n}
\end{document}
```

However this does not run, because each time the control exits the inner loop, the value of \nfac is reset to 1. I could not find any (without using packages) to retain the value of \nfac. Am I wrong somewhere? Please help.

Note: I used pdftex to compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, and congratulations for daring to explore TeX beyond well-trodden paths!

Comment: Changes to your variables are local to the group delimited by the braces `{}`. You have to prefix assignments with `\global` to make changes visible outside. E.g., try `\global\nfac \the\nfac\relax` in the loop.

Comment: Do you want your command to produce spurious spaces? If not, you need to comment them!

Comment: If you set LaTeX counters outside the loop i.e. `\newcounter` ..., changes within the loop should be global i.e. `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter` etc.

Comment: you never want to have the register allocation such as `\newcount` inside the loop, registers are a finite resource (although there are a lot more in etex than classic tex)

Comment: just a comment to confirm your impression one can compute with TeX/LaTeX. But there is intrinsic upper bound of `2^31-1` hence one needs a package to go beyond. Using e.g. [bnumexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bnumexpr), you can do `\thebnumexpr 100!\relax` and this will print ... no wait it goes into the margin, thus `\message{\thebnumexpr 100!\relax}` and you will get in the log `93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make assignments global using `\global` however you do not need any groups here so local assignments should be enough.  The following for example uses a recursive macro rather than a loop

```
\documentclass{article}

\typein[\n]{Enter the value of n :-}

\def\factorial#1{\ffactorial{#1}1}

\def\ffactorial#1#2{%
\ifnum#1=0 \the\numexpr#2\relax
\else
\ffactorial{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{\the\numexpr#1*#2\relax}%
\fi}
\begin{document}

\factorial{\n}

\end{document}
```

however if you enter a number larger than 12, you get arithmetic overflow due to the size of the integers.

It is possible of course to not use `\numexpr` (which is equivalent to the `\count` register usage in your version) and just encode an integer as a token list of the decimal expansion and encode the arithmetic by hand. There are packages for big integer arithmetic on ctan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am new to Latex and can't understand your code. Can you add comments and explain?

Comment: @MeetTaraviya it's the standard recursive definition of factorial written in tail recursive form for example it is algorithm B here http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7822

Answer (score 7):

There is a part of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161863/4686) (somewhere near the bottom half of it) which uses *no package* and computes binomial coefficients. The factorial `13!` already exceeds TeX's bound hence requires extending TeX's arithmetic, the code goes around that in order for example for `binomial(13,6)` to be evaluated (and quite bigger coefficients too). But if the final result exceeds `2^31` arithmetic overflow will occur.

The code uses e-TeX's `\numexpr` (as in David's answer here). This gives opportunity to write *expandable* code which adds a further twist to your programming challenge.

For convenience here it is copy pasted from original location.

*edit also copies over the comments which help understand the underlying maths*

```
% Expandably computing  binomial(n,k)=n choose k

% after having replaced k by the smallest of k and n-k, and checked if
% k=0, either one of the following products produces integers at each
% mutiply/divide steps: 

% n * (n-1)/2 * (n-2)/3 * .... * (n-k+1)/k

% or

% (n-k+1) * (n-k+2)/2 * (n-k+3)/3 * ... * n/k

% eTeX \numexpr does multiply/divide in one "double-precision" step,
% thus arithmetic overflow should not happen, as long as the result is <
% 2^31 (and naturally the initial n, binomial (2147483648,0) will not
% work

% For no special reason I chose the second product. 
% (notice that as k<n-k+1 also the first product is increasing, no 
% intermediate thing can cause overflow if the final thing does not)

% Each (n-k+j)/j step could be seen as (n-k)/j + 1, thus only j would need 
% incrementing;  up to the price of an extra addition, and I preferred to 
% carry around both an u=n-k+j and a v=j

% ALGORITHM
% replace k by the smallest of k and n-k
% if k=0 return 1
% else set w=n-k+1
%          u=n-k+2
%          v=2
% endif
% if v>k return w
% else
%        w<-w*u/v
%        u<-u+1
%        v<-v+1
% repeatif

% Constraint: expandability. Adding +1 has a cost and fetching a list of
% tokens also has one. To use one macro less, or not do twice u->u+1, 
% u and v are shifted from the start by  1 to be usable directly in the 
% updating of w.

% no check on validity of inputs

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% expandable macro \binomialb. No package needed. 

\catcode`_ 11

\def\binomialb #1#2{\romannumeral0\expandafter
    \binomialb_a\the\numexpr #1\expandafter.\the\numexpr #2.}

\def\binomialb_a #1.#2.{\expandafter\binomialb_b\the\numexpr #1-#2.#2.}

\def\binomialb_b #1.#2.{\ifnum #1<#2 \expandafter\binomialb_ca
                            \else   \expandafter\binomialb_cb
                            \fi {#1}{#2}}

\def\binomialb_ca #1{\ifnum#1=0 \expandafter \binomialb_one\else 
                    \expandafter \binomialb_d\fi {#1}}

\def\binomialb_cb #1#2{\ifnum #2=0 \expandafter\binomialb_one\else
                      \expandafter\binomialb_d\fi {#2}{#1}}

\def\binomialb_one #1#2{ 1}

\def\binomialb_d #1#2{\expandafter\binomialb_e \the\numexpr #2+1.#1!}

% n-k+1.k! -> u=n-k+2.v=2.w=n-k+1.k!
\def\binomialb_e #1.{\expandafter\binomialb_f \the\numexpr #1+1.2.#1.}

% u.v.w.k!
\def\binomialb_f #1.#2.#3.#4!%
{\ifnum #2>#4 \binomialb_end\fi
 \expandafter\binomialb_f
 \the\numexpr #1+1\expandafter.%
 \the\numexpr #2+1\expandafter.%
 \the\numexpr #1*#3/#2.#4!}

\def\binomialb_end #1*#2/#3!{\fi\space #2}
\catcode`_ 8
```

note1: some slight TeX optimization would replace the `+1` by `+\@ne`, the `>0<space>` by `>\z@`, etc...

note2: the use of `_` as private letter may disconcert, but it is fashionable and much more readable than the `@` ;-)

Comment: the `2^31-1` bound makes investing into sophisticated factorial algorithm a bit irrelevant as already `13!>2^21`. But for the record: it makes good sense to approach the problem via a binary splitting `N!=F(1,A) times F(A+1,N)` where `A`is about `N/2` and `F(u,v)` is `u(u+1)...v`. For this to be really efficient one then needs sub-quadratic (Karatsuba) multiplication. But even  without as in my package [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) this approach allows very short recursive definition which is almost as efficient as the much longer (dozens of lines) optimized code (say `N<= 2000` for `N!`.)