# Problem with Pascal triangle example

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've got a problem with Pascal triangle example at [Paul Gaborit's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198887/how-can-i-draw-pascals-triangle-with-some-its-properties?rq=1).

When I compile it with one of my personal class file, it compiles OK. But when I compile it with another class, using the same options for tikz libraries, I get an error on the line

```
\global\let\value=\value
```

The triangle is produced, as well as the rest of the document, but I get an error message :

```
./cours_denombrement.tex:810: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
               {
l.810 \end{document}

./cours_denombrement.tex:810: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               {
l.810 \end{document}
```

I think it has something to do with the interaction with another package, so I'm gonna investigate on my class file, but maybe someone has an idea about what is going on ?

Thanks for any help.

\bye

Comment: I can compile it without problems when using `pdflatex`. Which compiler do you use? Does replacing that line by `\xdef\value{\value}` help?

Comment: It gives a different error message : "Use of \value doesn't match its definition.". I use pdflatex too, and the most recent TeXLive. What I don't understand is that if I use a different class, the code compiles OK...

Comment: When you are saying "a differen class": which classes work and which don't? Notice that `\value` in this code is just a placeholder, you could replace all `\value`s by `\myvalue`, then. (It is arguably even a bit unfortunate that `\value` is used here as this is a standard command that can be used to e.g. get the value of a counter, so `\myvalue` is probably even cleaner.)

Comment: Your last "intuition" did the trick : replacing "value" by another name gave no error. I suppose I have some package loaded by my "courses" class that uses this name.

Comment: Glad to hear. What should we do now? I could write an answer because I actually do not think this is your fault, or one of us leaves a comment under the linked answer, hoping that `\value` gets replaced by something less dangerous. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe I'll post a comment to link to this page. Problem is : I don't have time to pinpoint the faulty extension that causes the problem :-(