# How to highlight the tetrahedral numbers in Pascal's triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

The tetrahedral numbers count the number of balls with equal radii needed to create a triangular pyramid with n layers.  The nth tetrahedral number is given by the formula C(n + 2, 3).  Accordingly, the tetrahedral numbers appear as a diagonal in Pascal's triangle.  I wish to highlight those numbers in Pascal's triangle.  However, what my attempt produced was Pascal's triangle with a separate row in which the highlighted numbers appeared in red.  How do I modify my code so that the tetrahedral numbers are highlighted in the triangle itself?

[image: tetrahedral_numbers]

Here is the code, which is based on Caramdir's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/pascals-triangle-in-tikz) about how to present the binomial coefficients in Pascal's triangle in numerical form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%calculate binomial coefficients 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialcoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \n in {0, ..., 7} {
            \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
                \node (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\(\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}\)};
                \foreach \n in {3, 4, ..., 7} \node[color = red] at (\n, 3) {\(\binomialcoefficient{\n}{3}\)};
            }
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{(\n+1)/2}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\n/2}
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should reference https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381631/color-on-odd-numbers-of-pascals-triangle since it's the orignal code for your MWE.

Comment: @JeT  Based on your comment, I found the actual source for my code, which I have now referenced.

Comment: Feel free to also add a visual like https://www.kosbie.net/lessonPlans/pascalsTriangle/ws4_pascalPatterns_solutions.html. It'll help others to figure out what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tetrahedral numbers in your algorithm are identified by the fact that the difference between the `\n` index and the `\k` index is equal to `3`.

So, just calculate this difference and color them as here :

```
\pgfmathparse{int(\n-\k)}
\ifnum \pgfmathresult=3
\node[red,node font=\bf] (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
\else
\node (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
\fi
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%calculate binomial coefficients 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialcoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \n in {0, ...,7} {
            \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
             \pgfmathparse{int(\n-\k)}
             \ifnum \pgfmathresult=3
             \node[red,node font=\bf] (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
             \else
             \node (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
             \fi
%                \foreach \n in {3, 4, ..., 7} \node[color = red] at (\n, 3) {\(\binomialcoefficient{\n}{3}\)};
            }
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{(\n+1)/2}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\n/2}
        }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

AndreC was too fast for me :)
Just an alternative to evaluate directly `\x`, `\y` and `\n-\k` directly in the loop and avoid `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

%calculate binomial coefficients 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialcoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \n in {0, ..., 11} 
    {
        \foreach [evaluate ={
                \x = int(0.5*(\n+1));
                \y = int(0.5*\n) ;
                \NmK = int(\n-\k) ; %n minus k, NmK
            }] \k in {0,...,\n} 
        {
            \ifnum  \NmK=3          
                \node[red,node font=\bf] (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
            \else
                \node (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
            \fi             

        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The nice solutions by AndreC and JeT both highlight the C(n + 2, n - 1) entries, with n being at least 1.  Since I was interested in highlighting the C(n + 2, 3) entries, again with n being at least 1, I modified AndreC's code to highlight the opposite diagonal as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%calculate binomial coefficients 
\makeatletter
\newcommand\binomialcoefficient[2]{%
    % Store values 
    \c@pgf@counta=#1% n
    \c@pgf@countb=#2% k
    %
    % Take advantage of symmetry if k > n - k
    \c@pgf@countc=\c@pgf@counta%
    \advance\c@pgf@countc by-\c@pgf@countb%
    \ifnum\c@pgf@countb>\c@pgf@countc%
        \c@pgf@countb=\c@pgf@countc%
    \fi%
    %
    % Recursively compute the coefficients
    \c@pgf@countc=1% will hold the result
    \c@pgf@countd=0% counter
    \pgfmathloop% c -> c*(n-i)/(i+1) for i=0,...,k-1
        \ifnum\c@pgf@countd<\c@pgf@countb%
        \multiply\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@counta%
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by-1%
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by1%
        \divide\c@pgf@countc by\c@pgf@countd%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
    \the\c@pgf@countc%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \n in {0, ...,7} {
            \foreach \k in {0,...,\n} {
             \ifnum \k=3
             \node[red,node font=\bf] (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
             \else
             \node (\n\k) at (\k-\n/2,-\n) {\binomialcoefficient{\n}{\k}};
             \fi
%                \foreach \n in {3, 4, ..., 7} \node[color = red] at (\n, 3) {\(\binomialcoefficient{\n}{3}\)};
            }
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{(\n+1)/2}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\n/2}
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Pascal's_triangle_with_the_tetrahedral_numbers_highlighted]