# Arithmetic overflow in TiKZ/pgfmath

Tags: pgfmath, arithmetic

I am writing some material on the trinomial theorem and Pascal's pyramid, and I'm trying to typeset a single layer.  Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int trunc}

\small
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{8}
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\n}
  {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\i}
    {
      \draw (\j-\i*0.5,\i*0.866,) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(-0.5,-0.866) -- cycle;
      \node[align=center] at (0.1+\j-\i*0.5,-0.65+\i*0.866)
      {\pgfmathparse{factorial(\n)/factorial(\n-\i)%
       /factorial(\j)/factorial(\i-\j)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This works fine up to n=7, but crashes with an arithmetic overflow on n=8.  As you can see, the computation is simply finding the values of some multinomial coefficients.  But why the crash on n=8?  And what's the best way around it?

Comment: I see. You are right`\pgfmathparse{factorial(8)}\pgfmathresult; ` and also `\pgfmathparse{8!}\pgfmathresult;` does not work for some reasons. (also all values greater doesn't work for me) Error: `! Arithmetic overflow.
\pgfmath@iterate ...pgfmath@x by\c@pgfmath@counta
\advance \c@pgfmath@counta...
l.25 \pgfmathparse{factorial(8)}
\pgfmathresult;
I can't carry out that multiplication or division,
since the result is out of range.`

Comment: You might get help by https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17522/95544. A couple of the answers implement the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Ah! page 923 of the TiKZ/pgf manual: "calculations must not exceed ±16383.99999 at any point,"   Well, that explains it.  So clearly I need another package such as `xint` for my computations, or farm my computations to an external package such as GNU Maxima or Sage.

Comment: This would be trivial with LuaLaTeX......

Comment: I'm sure that LuaLaTeX may well be the answer to my dreams... but in the end I used `xint` instead of `pgfmath`, and computed the numbers I wanted with `{\xinttheexpr binomial(\n,\i)*binomial(\i,\j)\relax}`.

Comment: @Alasdair could you add your solution as an answer?